# Ajax form submit and get query strings and append to new page and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am looking for a way to submit a form using ajax, redirect to a URL and send the data on it, and also get the query strings on the URL. Basically, a normal GET request, This is what I tried

```js
$('#searchform').submit(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/list",
    data: $("#searchform").serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      $(".loader").show();
    },
    success: function(data) {
      location.href = "/list"; //redirect to list
      $("#ajaxcontent").empty(); //try to append data on this div, not sure how 
      $("#ajaxcontent").append(data);
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I want to get the query string as such

```
/list?input1=thisinput&input2=anotherinput
```

Same things as you receive from a GET request.

All in all, my only purpose of using ajax on this is to show the preloader.

Will someone be kind and patient enough to help me explain how should I make my ajax request. I hope I have made myself understandable.

This is the form

```
<form method="GET" action="list" id="searchform" name="searchform">

    <input type="text" name="search1">
    <input type="text" name="search2">
    <input type="text" name="search3">
<button type="submit" id="submitz">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Do you have a problem with the code? It looks fine in isolation. Also, redirecting directly after making an AJAX request makes the entire point of the AJAX (and the `empty()` and `append()` calls) pretty redundant.

Comment: Setting location.href redirects the browser. At that point in time, the browser stops executing any code following `location.href` and whatever script(s) present in the new resource is/are loaded/executed.

Comment: But my ajax code is not getting the query string as I am looking for. And also as Rory said, after redirecting the whole ajax request has no point, I don't know what I should do

Comment: In that case we'd need to see the HTML of your `#searchform` to help you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have added the form code as well

Comment: Your code is working fine, so I don't understand where the problem is. I tested in a snippet, but am unable to link to it at the moment as jsFiddle is in read-only mode.

Comment: You can not redirect to a new page and run code on it.... So use ` $("#searchform").serialize()` on the href line?

Comment: Maybe redirect to `'/list?' + $('#searchform').serialize();` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using two ways of communication with \list.

At first, you're sending an ajax request at \list (with the .ajax() function), this request contact \list, give it your form data, and send some data back (in the success function).

Next, you use a simple javascript redirection to \list without any data.

So you have to make a choice, either :

-keeping the ajax request (just drop the location.href = "/list"; then), but you'll stay on the same page (you are appending data just fine btw). It will require some content returned from \list, use and abuse of console.log(data); to see what you got here.

-dropping the ajax request for the simple redirection, but then the loader will be nearly invisible, since the page change will be quite fast. So you'll be better off without any JS. To test it :

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(event) {
  $(".loader").show();
  location.href = "/list?"+$("#searchform").serialize(); //redirect to list
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. For the second option is there a way to show that loader for a longer time so that it keeps on shows until another page is loaded

Comment: Nope, when you change page, you also change document, html, head&body, etc... so there's no way to interact here. If you want the loader to be shown, you'll have to use the jQuery option.